# Quantum fields as absolute observers?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, reference-frames, observers

I think I might be asking a stupid question and I might be corrected quite quickly on this, but I will ask it anyway.

---

**Question**

Since quantum fields are everywhere in space and can create and annihilate particles at a given location, can these same quantum fields be considered as absolute observers or as an absolute reference frame where motion and other relative properties can be determined?

**Example**

You cannot detect if you are moving according to relativity, but with an absolute reference frame (a quantum field) you *can* detect if you are moving or not.

---

**Are they considered observers?**

Are quantum fields even considered observers/reference frames in the first place? If not, then how come fermion fields (matter, car, person, etc) count as observers/reference frames then?

---

**A contradiction?**

If quantum fields can be considered as absolute observers/reference frames, then wouldn't this contradict Einstein’s theory of relativity?

Since Einstein’s theory of relativity has not been contradicted (otherwise it would have been widespread news), then I am surely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's best to answer this question first in the context of classical field theory.

In classical field theory on curved spacetimes, we don't usually consider field equations and observables which single out a preferred reference frame.  (You *can* do this, but it's not very useful for doing gravity or electromagnetism.)  But it does (frequently) happen that a particular solution to the field equations picks out a preferred frame of reference.  One of the most famous examples of this is the "rest frame" of the cosmic microwave background; this is the reference frame in which the CMBR appears most spherically symmetric.  (The photons aren't actually at rest in any frame, but there's a frame in which they're moving any which way with equal probability.)   Not all solutions of field equations pick out a rest frame though.  For example, you can define classical $\phi^4$ theory on a curved background, and the zero solution $\phi=0$ doesn't single out any nice collection of reference frames.

The same things happen in quantum field theory.  The dynamic equations and observables don't single out a preferred basis.  But the solutions of the theory -- the choice of a given state vector, either given explicitly or via correlation functions on the obserbables -- do often pick out preferred reference frames.  For example, I am typing this while sitting in a chair.

So, there's no contradiction to worry about.

Comment: So the equations themselves do not pick out the QF as a reference frame, or any other one for that matter. I am guessing you could artificially introduce an absolute observer/reference frame, but it would not count as a valid description of reality. I know that not all math does this, but for the sake of understanding, let's say that our math should describe reality.

Comment: Yes, the interesting dynamical laws are relativistically covariant, so they don't pick out a particular frame.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum fields are Lorentz invariants. The easiest example is the electromagnetic field: different frames observe the same field for its effects (movement of a charge for example). But the components of the Faraday tensor ($E_i$ and $B_i$) are not the same, but change according to Lorentz transformation between the frames.

The same happens for the tensors of fermion fields. The current in a wire is the same if it is moving or at rest in my frame. But if it is at rest, only the electrons are flowing. If the wire has a relative movement, protons are also flowing.

Comment: So you are saying that QFs have the same physics as all other objects? I understand that as QFs are not any different in being a reference frame than a person or a car?

Comment: Well, the easiest example is the Higgs field, which is a Lorentz scalar, and doesn't change.

Comment: @Tachyon I think that calling a person or a car as reference frames is just a shortcut for "the reference frame where this person or that car is at rest."